# Firebase Auth and Caledar API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I am trying to log in a user and create an event in their calendar.

I am using [Firebase Auth](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-web/#using_firebaseui%20for%20authentication) and [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js). I am not sure how I can use Firebase Access Token to create event for the user.

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
      initApp = function() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            user.getIdToken().then(function(accessToken) {
            //how can I use this accessToken to create event in the calendar?
            });
          } else {}
        }, function(error) {});
      };

      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        initApp();
      });
    </script>
```

I have a script that can log in a user and I have a script that can create an event (code not posted because the code is very similar to the attached links). How can I combine these two tasks?

From reading the documentation, I know that I have to add Calendar scopes and discovery documents to the auth script. However, I am struggling with the next steps.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Firebase ID token to call Google Calendar APIs.

You need to use the [Google JS library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) to sign in to Google and to call [calendar APIs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js). You can then get the Google ID token token to sign in with Firebase.

```
// Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
// Sign in with credential from the Google user.
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
  .then((authResult) => {
    // User signed in with Firebase.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error while signing in.
  });
```